# How to use the pdfLibNet.dll in silverlight 4?

Tags: silverlight

I can use the pdfLibnet.dll in C#

but, it is not use in silverlight 4.

How to use the pdfLibnet.dll in silverlight 4??

Comment: Silverlight is not compatible with any regular .net class library. You need to download the source and convert the source to a silverlight Class library to recompile it against. Unless they have their own Silverlight class library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# != Silverlight

They use different runtimes so you can only use Silverlight compatible dlls as references in Silverlight.